# Article usage in technical texts: a unique and other cases

Tags: articles, technical, resources

Sometimes I write technical texts and wonder which article I should use before adjectives like *unique, so-called* and *given*, as English is a foreign language for me. For example, why it is

> *there is a unique number such that...*

or

> *necessary tools include the so-called Bott's formula...*

Could you recommend me an online resourse to resolve such ambiguities: a table of adjectives with necessary articles or something like that?

Comment: You shouldn't need a table to be honest, the rule for articles is fairly simple: if you're referring to a specific occurrence or instance of a thing, use "the". If you're referring to it generally, use "a". In your examples, the reason "a" is used is that the unique number isn't specified; it could be anything. However, "Bott's formula" is a specific thing. It will only be whatever Bott's formula is, no matter what. So you'd use "the".

Comment: In other words, you don't need to worry about the adjective, worry about whether the noun is specific or non-specific and you can't go wrong.

Comment: @JohnClifford Are you kidding?  The usage of English articles is idiomatic, and the full rules are quite complicated and baffling, especially to people whose first language has no articles.  Try explaining the rules that govern the differences between *I like the dog*, *I like a dog*, and *I like dog*.  Then try it for the plural.

Comment: In the first you mean a specific dog, in the second you mean no particular dog, and the third means you have strange dietary tastes. :P

Comment: Actually, 'a dog' means a particular dog, but one that is known to the speaker but not yet to the listener.  Once mentioned, it becomes 'the dog' to both parties.

Comment: @deadrat But his main point is still valid: the adjective is irrelevant. If there were more than one Bott's formula, you would say _a so-called Bott's formula_.

Comment: @JohnClifford Are you maligning my dietary tastes?  But just to emphasize my point, suppose someone asks me, "What kind of pet do you prefer?" I could say, "For loyalty, you have to admire the dog."  But I'm not talking about a specific dog, but dogs in general.

Comment: @Barmar I was addressing the specific/non-specific part of JC's comment. It's not always as easy outside of Bott's formula, which reminds of the Groucho Marx line: *Outside of a dog, a book is man's best friend. Inside of a dog it's too dark to read.*  Groucho didn't mean one, unspecified dog.  He meant all dogs.